# No seek on mobile devices (Vimeo)

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have two questions. I want to disable the seek functionality in my Vimeo player. Therefore I have written this code:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var iframe = $('.media-vimeo-player')[0];
        var player = $f(iframe);
        var seeked = new Boolean(false);

            player.addEvent('ready', function() {

            player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
            player.addEvent('seek', onSeek);
            player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
        });

            function onFinish(id) {
                $('img').show();
        }

            function onSeek(data, id){
            if(seeked == false){
                seeked = true;
                player.api('seekTo', old_time);
            } else{
            seeked = false;
            }   
        }

            function onPlayProgress(data, id){
                    if(Math.abs(data.seconds - old_time) <= 1.00){
                old_time = data.seconds;
            }
            }
   });  
})(jQuery);
```

With this code the current time will be saved in a variable ("old_time"). If the user seeks the video, the player will jump back to the latest old time. On desktop this code runs mostly fine. But sometimes the player jumps back to start instead of the "old_time" position. Can somebody exlain this behavior please?

Furthermore - and this is the more important question - this code doesn't completely work on a mobile device. When I press the play button the video enters fullscreen with the smartphone's default video player. I can seek to a position wherever I want to seek and the player seeks to this position instead of jumping back to the "old_time" position. First I thought that this happens, because the Vimeo Javascript API doesn't support the seek function on the HTML mobile player (see https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#event-compatibility), but then I realised, that the finish event works fine: after finishing the video the browser closed the fullscreen mode and displays the img element, which was hidden when the side was loaded. So I guess that the seek event should work as well. Can someone please give me an advise what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the old_time variable in the same section as the iframe, player, and seeked variables.

```
var iframe = $('.media-vimeo-player')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);
var seeked = new Boolean(false);
var old_time = 0;
```